# PHP execute code after csv export

Tags: php, csv, export

I am trying to export a csv file and then finish executing code afterwards however everything after the fclose is still exported into my csv. 
This is a simplified version of my code:

```
$file = fopen("php://output","w");
foreach ($export as $design){
    foreach ($design as $line){
        fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
    }
}
fclose($file);
echo "do not export me";    
return;
```

The echo statement is exporting into the csv.

Am I not closing the file properly?

Comment: Do you want to export the csv to disk on the server or do you want to serve a csv to the client as a download?

Comment: to the client as a download

Comment: You can only serve either a CSV as a download OR a (HTML) web page, not both.

Comment: I was afraid you might say that. What is the best way to supply the client with a download and then direct them to a confirmation page?

Comment: Reverse it. Redirect to the confirmation page and trigger AJAX for download script, with alternative - 'if it didn't start to download, click here'

Comment: Ok so I reversed my script, but now I only get the raw data returned not a downloadable file. I have found this link that says ajax will not allow downloads. http://goo.gl/I5gXnO. Am I missing something?